# How to solve $\int_{-4}^{4}x^2\sqrt{16-x^2 }dx$ with beta function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, beta-function

I need to solve the integral with use of the beta function.

I have tried derationalization of the square root, got nowhere. I tried some substitutions, but the thing is I never got the bounds right.

I would need help solving this.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but the substitution $x=4\sin\theta$ converts your integral to $$256\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta \, d\theta \, .$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that integrated function $f(x)$ is even. Thus this integral equals to $2\int_0^4 f(x) dx$. Then make variable replacement $t=\frac{x^2}{16}$.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the Beta function, which was the focus of the question. So this shouldn't have been the accepted answer either.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=4u$ to transform the integral to
$$16^2\int_{-1}^1u^2\sqrt{1-u^2}\,du=2\cdot16^2\int_0^1u^2\sqrt{1-u^2}\,du$$
Then $v=u^2,du=\frac1{2\sqrt v}\,dv$:
$$=16^2\int_0^1v^{1-1/2}(1-v)^{1/2}\,dv=16^2\mathrm B(3/2,3/2)=32\pi$$

Comment: I don't know much about the Beta function other than it's definition. How did you determine that $B( 3/2, 3/2) = \frac{\pi}{8}\ ?$

Comment: @AdamRubinson Gamma function + $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt\pi$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson There are easier ways to solve this problem, without the beta function. You can do a simple trigonometric substitution $x=4\sin u$.

Comment: @Andrei That is obvious. However, the question specifically asked how to carry out the integration *with* the beta function.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{-4}^{4}x^2\sqrt{16-x^2 }dx=2\int_{0}^{4}x^2\sqrt{16-x^2 }dx=8\int_0^4x^2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{16}}dx$$
Now make substitution $u=\frac{x^2}{16}$, $du=\frac18xdx$. The $u$ limits are from $0$ to $1$.